# how do disable/remove Zip Code for specific country in magento 2

Tags: magento2, address, zipcode

How can i disable/remove Zip Code for specific country in **magento 2**

For example if some one select UAE than Zip Code field should remove or disable else it should visible.

Comment: Yes, it possible , need to work some files

Comment: Accept the answer If you find it helpful @Waqar

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove the `Zip Code` based on country selection, then firstly you can make `zip code` optional for this country from backend (i.e UAE), from `store > config > general > Zip/Postal Code is Optional for` and un-select your country which you want.

then you can override below `javascript` in your custom module

`magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/post-code.js`,

By adding

`app/code/YOURVENDOR/YOURMODULE/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code": 'YOURVendor_YOURMODULE/js/form/element/post-code'
        }
    }
};
```

Now copy `post-code` into your module directory

`app/code/YOURVENDOR/YOURMODULE/view/frontend/web/js/form/element/post-code.js`

With below javascript,

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @api
 */
define([
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    './abstract'
], function (_, registry, Abstract) {
    'use strict';

    return Abstract.extend({
        defaults: {
            imports: {
                update: '${ $.parentName }.country_id:value'
            }
        },

        /**
         * @param {String} value
         */
        update: function (value) {
            var country = registry.get(this.parentName + '.' + 'country_id'),
                options = country.indexedOptions,
                option;

            if (!value) {
                return;
            }

            option = options[value];

            if (option['is_zipcode_optional']) { // from here custom code start 
                    // if country is optional then make it hide,
                this.hide();                
            } else {
                this.validation['required-entry'] = true;
            }

            this.required(!option['is_zipcode_optional']);
        }
    });
});
```

After doing this, perform `cache:flush` and `static-content:deploy`

**EDIT**

---

If you are using custom theme then you can simply copy `post-code.js` into your custom theme path, but this js path should be,

`app/design/yourvendor/yourthemename/Magento_Ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/`

Comment: rather `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Ui/web/js/form/element/post-code.js`

Answer (score 2):

I have disabled the field by using jquery

first I made "zip code" field optional from admin for UAE.

then added a js file in theme Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<link src="js/disable_zip_code.js" />
```

then placed the js file in /web/js/disable_zip_code.js

and write the following code in js file

```
    require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $( ".country #country" ).change(function() {

      if($(this).val()=="AE" || $(this).val()=="ae" ){
        $(".zip #zip").attr("disabled","");
      }
      else{
        $(".zip #zip").removeAttr("disabled");
      }
      });


    //for checkout fields

    $("body").on("change","select[name='country_id']", function(){

      if($( "[name='country_id']" ).val()=="AE" || $( "[name='country_id']" ).val()=="ae" ){
        $("[name='postcode']").attr("disabled","");
      }
      else{
        $("[name='postcode']").removeAttr("disabled");
      }
      });


  });

});
```

now its working

Answer (score 0):

Work for me

```
<item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```