# Magento2: How to remove zip code in magento 2 address book page?

Tags: magento2, checkout

How to remove zipcode field in magento 2 address book[image]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196901/how-do-disable-remove-zip-code-for-specific-country-in-magento-2 check this

Answer (score 0):

You can remove by layout file.

```
<item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
</item>
```

Comment: sir please tell me which file

Comment: Please check /module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml Firstly override this and hide.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the checkout_index_index.xml by going to app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/Magento_Checkout/layout and do a checkout_index_index.xml file.

Then remove it using

```
<item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
<item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
</item>
```

in the same file line number 208

Comment: Actually this file is only available in vendor file. i already change this file but no change

Comment: Have  you  performed the above steps & clear cache & checked ?

Comment: yes but not working